# How do I edit a milestone date in developer story?

Tags: bug, developer-story

I was very excited to add the 10th anniversary of my career as a milestone in my developer story on Stack Overflow.

I entered the month and year when I started my career for the milestone where it asks when it started. But that is appearing at the 2009 level in my story rather than it should appear on the top as current milestone.

And now I do not have any edit option there.

Comment: To be somewhat pedantic, your milestone *didn't* start in 2009. The milestone ("10 Years as a Developer") started in 2019. In that regard, it doesn't immediately strike me as a bug. Unless perhaps the justification behind the "bug" tag is the lack of an edit button?

Comment: I see it in two places on your Deleoper Story. Once in 2009 and once in 2019, but the second one, where you complete your 10 years, is showing below your current positions/projects (understandably). Maybe you didn't see this second mark?

Comment: @Tyler yes.. I mean it is a bug that it does not allow to edit it while other story types we are able to edit.

Comment: @George I have added the second one myself after I realised the issue with first one. So I should still be at least able to delete the incorrect information and retain the new one.

Comment: Pulling the tag off here since the developer story has been sunset.